# SQL Comparison Query Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with transaction history for 3 years, I need to compare the sum ( transaction) for 12 months with sum( transaction) for 4 weeks and display the customer list with the result set.

```
Table Transaction_History

Customer_List  Transaction   Date
1                  200     01/01/2014
2                  200     01/01/2014
1                  100     10/24/2014
1                  100     11/01/2014
2                  200     11/01/2014
```

The output should have only Customer_List with 1 because sum of 12 months transactions equals sum of 1 month transaction.

I am confused about how to find the sum for 12 months and then compare with same table sum for 4 weeks.

Comment: Does your transaction table has entry of all 12 months for each Customer? Or is there any possibility that there may not have entry for particular month for Customer

Comment: Please explain your expected result of only having customer_list 1.

Comment: Customer can be with no entries in between those 12 months sum (transaction of 12 months ) if equal to sum ( transaction of 4 weeks) then display else dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query below will work, except your sample data doesnt make sense

total for customer 1 for the last 12 months in your data set = 400
total for customer 1 for the last 4 weeks in your data set = 200

unless you want to exclude the last 4 weeks, and not be a part of the last 12 months?

then you would change the "having clause" to:

```
having
sum(case when Dt >= '01/01/2014' and dt <='12/31/2014' then (trans) end) - sum(case when Dt >= '10/01/2014' and dt <= '11/02/2014' then (trans) end) = 
    sum(case when Dt >= '10/01/2014' and dt <= '11/02/2014' then (trans) end)
```

of course doing this would mean your results would be customer 1 and 2

```
 create table #trans_hist
(Customer_List int, Trans int, Dt Date)

insert into #trans_hist (Customer_List, Trans , Dt ) values 
(1,                  200,     '01/01/2014'),
(2,                  200,     '01/01/2014'),
(1,                  100,     '10/24/2014'),
(1,                  100,     '11/01/2014'),
(2,                  200,     '11/01/2014')

select 

Customer_List




from #trans_hist

group by 
Customer_List


having
sum(case when Dt >= '01/01/2014' and dt <='12/31/2014' then (trans) end) = 
    sum(case when Dt >= '10/01/2014' and dt <= '11/02/2014' then (trans) end)





drop table #trans_hist
```

Comment: I have one small doubt regarding the case in having if my date column is in different table how do  I use that table details in having and compare sum of transactions

Comment: join the table based on date, or create a cte or temp table to get the data to all line up the way you want to then query the cte or temp table

Comment: hard to help you if you dont have any visuals for us. we dont know how to bring the date table in etc.

if you can get data to looklike what you posted above then you should be able to figure it out from there

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a self join.

```
select yourfields
from yourtable twelvemonths join yourtable fourweeks on something
where fourweek.something is within a four week period
and twelvemonths.something is within a 12 month period
```

You should be able to work out the details.

Answer (score 1):

If your transactions are always positive and you want customers whose 12-month totals equal the 4-week total, then you want customers who have transactions in the past four weeks but not in the preceding 12 months - 4 weeks.

You can get this more directly using aggregation and a `having` clause.  The logic is to check for any transactions in the past year that occurred before the previous 4 weeks:

```
select Customer_List
from Transaction_History
where date >= dateadd(month, -12, getdate())
group by CustomerList
having min(date) >= dateadd(day, -4 * 7, getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here for methods to aggregate by month, year, etc.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx